# Writing a recursive function but getting infinite loop

Tags: python, image, loops, recursion

I am using Python and I have been tasked to write a recursive loop. The idea is to form a picture where there are vertical rows:

```
1st row: 1 object  (2**0)
2nd row: 2 object  ( 2**1)
3rd row: 4 obj      (2**2)
4th:     8 obj       (2**3)
```

and so on until `n` rows and `n` columns.

Through using 'stack' and 'beside' functions, I need to formulate that pattern.

My code is:

```
def fractal(Pattern, n):
    if n== 1:
        return beside( Pattern, n)
    else:
        return beside( fractal(Pattern, n-1), fractal(Pattern, n))
```

However, when I want to show the overall pattern, there is an infinite loop.

Comment: You must be missing a base case. Identify the smallest unit where you can return without calling the function again.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `return beside( fractal(Pattern, n-1), fractal(Pattern, n-2))` or something?

Comment: `fractal(Pattern, n)` calls `fractal(Pattern, n)` in the last line. That's infinite recursion... aka [inception](http://spdevlab.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Go-Deeper-Inception-Movie.jpg)

Answer (score 7):

You are calling `fractal(Pattern, n)` inside `fractal(Pattern, n)`.  It will never stop doing that (at least till it runs out of stack).

Answer (score 1):

Part of the `return` from the `else` condition is `fractal(Pattern, n)`, the exact same arguments as currently inside. That path will never reach `n == 1`

Without knowing more, I can't say the solution. Just the source of the infinite recursion.